# PC Phone Modem Software

Tags: modem, telephony

I'm looking for a piece of software that will let me hook a phone line up to my PC Modem and place calls over it using my mic and computer speakers.  Does anyone have any experience with anything like this?

Comment: Would really be interested in software like this as well, preferably for linux (Ubuntu).. Anyone have any suggestions in that direction?

Comment: @Tim, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tools for [voice modem](http://www.modemsite.com/56K/voice.asp) software are:

- [Ring Central](http://www.ringcentral.com/)
- [BVRP](http://www.bvrp.com/)
- [Messaging Software](http://www.messaging-software.com/telephony-software.htm)

For Linux:

- [VOCP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vocp/)

Comment: http://www.vocpsystem.com is now, apparently, a website for a marketing services company. Check http://sourceforge.net/projects/vocp/

Answer (score 1):

U.S. Robotics are still giving away the **[BVRP PhoneTools](http://www.usr.com/bvrp/bvrp.asp?loc=trky)**, excellent software.

Comment: As I read it, this will only work with their products. Or am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: nah, the BVRP Phone Tools work with any V.92 modem.