# Connecting a landline phone through the PC

Tags: phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PC Phone Modem Software](https://superuser.com/questions/88579/pc-phone-modem-software)

I have both a landline and a mobile and would like to make calls through the PC. How do I connect the phoneline into the PC (do I need an ethernet card?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your Ethernet card. It might look like a similar connector, but is a completely different system.

You need something like one of these devices to connect a phone to your PC, then you can use services like skype to connect to phones:
http://www.von-phone.com/skype-adapters.php

If this is for a larger system with several phones, take a look at Asterisk:
http://www.asterisk.org/